# CRM / IIS :How to add application to Microsoft Dynamics CRM site iis

Tags: iis, crm

I want add web API inner web site Microsoft Dynamics CRM in IIS 7,

I am try create but error :

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Please help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CRM 2011 adding anything into the CRM web application folder is not supported or recommended. Just create a new IIS site for the API.